# Не понимаю как работает запрос SQL (sqlalchemy, 2x outerjoin , count)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Приветствую сообщество ru.stackoverflow! Я задал 2 дня [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1428716/sql-%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc-2x) и получил на него корректный ответ. Задача была сделать запрос подсчета количества яблок для садовода, при том, что у садовода может быть несколько деревьев, а у каждого дерева может быть несколько яблок. Правильным быстрым(мой прежний код работал очень долго) ответом стало:

```
select g.gardener_id g.name, count(a.apple_id) apples_qty from gardeners g
LEFT JOIN trees t on t.gard_id = g.gardener_id
LEFT JOIN apples a on a.ap_tree_id = t.tree_id
GROUP BY g.gardener_id, g.name
```

Я разобрался с запросом и решил перенести это в sqlalchemy. Вот, что у меня получилось после очень долгих мучений:

```
def apples_count(name: str) -> int:
    return (session.query(Gardener, sqlalchemy.func.count(AppleTrees.tree_id))
                .outerjoin(AppleTrees)
                .group_by(Gardener)
                .outerjoin(Apples)
                .group_by(Gardener)
                .filter(Gardener.name == name)
            ).all()[0][1]
```

Код работает исправно, но я не понимаю, как это мы считаем количество деревьев count(AppleTrees.tree_id), а получаем корректное количество яблок(испр. неверное утверждение - не будет работать, если дерево пустое). При этом я пытался искать именно Gardener, sqlalchemy.func.count(Apple.apple_id) - но у меня вообще никак не получалось.

Вот такой код выдает sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT gardener.gardener_id AS gardener_gardener_id, gardener.name AS gardener_name, count(trees.tree_id) AS count_1 FROM gardener
LEFT OUTER JOIN trees ON gardener.gardener_id = trees.gard_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN aples ON trees.tree_id = aples.ap_tree_id 
WHERE gardener.name = %(name_1)s
GROUP BY gardener.gardener_id
```

Напомню таблицы

```
class Gardener(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'gardeners'

    gardener_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(15))
    apple_trees = relationship('AppleTrees', backref='gardener_trees')


class AppleTrees(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trees'

    tree_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    gard_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('gardeners.gardener_id'))
    apples = relationship('Apples', backref='tree_apples')


class Apples(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'apples'
    apple_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ap_tree_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('trees.tree_id'))
```

Comment: *я не понимаю, как это мы считаем количество деревьев count(AppleTrees.tree_id), а получаем корректное количество яблок.* Это исключительно потому, что у тебя нет ни одного дерева без яблок. Будь такие - и результат станет неверным.

Comment: Согласен, решение некорректное. Тогда понять бы как на алхимии составить корректный запрос(